# How to trim spaces in NetLogo

Tags: string, netlogo, trim

How do I trim spaces in NetLogo. I have a string named "Net Logo" with a space in between "Net" and "Logo". I want to remove the space and show "NetLogo". How can I do it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out `remove " " "Net Logo"`